# Java: Finding the Highest and Lowest Score

Tags: java

I'm struggling with a problem I have in my Java class. First here are my directions to the program so you understand what I'm trying to do:

Write an application that allows a user to enter any number of test scores until the user enters 999. If the score entered is less than 0 or more than 100, display an appropriate message and do not use the score. After the scores have been entered, display the number of scores entered, the high score, the lowest score, and the arithmetic average.

---There are several things going wrong. My if statement is not validating the answer right if it doesn't equal 1 or 999. It works the first time, but if I put the answer in wrong, it goes to the while statement instead of prompting the user to re-enter either number 1 or 999.
---Second, I can't get the lowest score, but the highest works.

Here is my code:

```
package chp6homework;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestScoreStatistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testScore;
        int totalTests = 0;
        int totalSum = 0;
        int answer;
        double average = 0;
        int hightScore = 0;
        int lowestScore = 0;

        // Prompts user for input
        System.out.print("Enter 1 to input a score.\n");
        System.out.print("Enter 999 to get results and exit. >> ");
        answer = input.nextInt();

        if(answer != 1 && answer != 999)
        {
            System.out.print("Invaild number!\n");
            System.out.print("Enter 1 to input a score.\n");
            System.out.print("Enter 999 to get results and exit. >> ");
            answer = input.nextInt();
        }

         while(answer == 1)
         {
            System.out.print("Please enter a test score >> ");
            testScore =  input.nextInt();

            if(testScore < 0 || testScore > 100)
            {
                System.out.print("Invalid score! \n");
                System.out.print("please enter a score that is not less than zero and" +
                        " and not more than 100. >> ");
                testScore =  input.nextInt();
            }
            totalSum = totalSum + testScore;
            ++totalTests;

            lowestScore = testScore;

            if(testScore > hightScore)
            {
                hightScore = testScore;
            }
            else if(testScore < lowestScore) 
            {
                lowestScore = testScore;
            }

            System.out.println("Your score was processed.");
            System.out.print("Enter 1 to input a score.\n");
            System.out.print("Enter 999 to get results and exit.\n");
            answer = input.nextInt();

         }

        average = totalTests * totalSum;

        System.out.println("The number of tests: " + totalTests);
        System.out.println("The total tests are: "+ totalSum);
        System.out.println("The average of scores is: " + average);
        System.out.println("Highest score: " + hightScore);
        System.out.println("Lowest score: " + lowestScore);
        }
}
```

Comment: Long methods are bad, break your code down into multiple methods. every method does one thing. Iy makes it easier to read and work on.

Comment: "My if statement is not validating the answer right [...] but if I put the answer in wrong, it goes to the while" <- Thats just how branch conditions work. If statements don't automatically loop or repeat until they are fulfilled. If the condition is not fulfilled the if block will be skipped. If you want to loop there you have to write a loop yourself.

Comment: *There are several things going wrong*. Take a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Seems it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

To get a mental overview use abstractions:

```
System.out.print("Enter a score or 999 to exit. >> ");
while (read a number && number != 999) {
    if (number out of valid range) {
        System.out.print("A score must be between 1 and 100. >> ");
    } else {
        add score to statistics
    }
    System.out.print("Enter a score or 999 to exit. >> ");
}
```

As this is home work I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Ok I did what you guided me to do and I figured it out!